# irregular grid using CSS

Tags: css, layout, grid

I am trying to display images using the following grid:

[image]

I'm having trouble stacking 2 smaller thumbnails on top of each other when they are on the left, like in the first row.

Comment: Post your current HTML/CSS on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Actually post the (relevant, minimal) HTML/CSS here in your post please. Just click [edit] and note the code formatting tools.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to achieve that kind of a grid. (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/ygtYx/ )

The HTML...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col narrow stack">
        <div>img goes here...</div>
        <div>img goes here...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col large">img goes here...</div>
    <div class="col narrow">img goes here...</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col narrow">img goes here...</div>
    <div class="col large">img goes here...</div>
    <div class="col narrow stack">
        <div>img goes here...</div>
        <div>img goes here...</div>
    </div>
</div>
​
​
```

The CSS...

```
.row,
.col,
.stack > div {
    /* 
      I usually just apply 
      this to all elements using 
      the * selector. You might not
      want to, so I put it here 
     */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.col {
    float: left
}

.col.narrow {
    width: 25%;
}

.col.large {
    width: 50%;
}

.stack > div {
    height: 50%;
}
```

I hope it's self explanatory, and easy to customize.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There is some way to archive that, The easiest is to add both smaller thumbnails in one other div that have the same height of the other div and then add both in it.
Be sure to calculate the margin, padding and border to fit the height.

Please add you code so I could see whats wrong.